# Need to understand Regex advanced substring, replace and split to make work with PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell-3.0

In forums, have seen the signature as:

```
[string](0..9 | %{[char][int](32+("......................."
    ).substring(($_*2), 2))}) -replace "\s{1}\b"
```

it gives the result as an email address.

Need to understand the substring and replace syntax here and to be precise the complete syntax how it is being evaluated.

I understand that `[string]` is a data type, then foreach every digit from 1 to 9 following result can be in integer or character and finding the ASCII value followed by finding the substring which is multiplied by 2 ***(don't understand why)*** and taking only 2 digits of result ***(result will be be of 2 digits then why to)***, then comes the replace which replaces with white space and the end \b signifies the word end boundary.

Also, as mentioned in http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html, how

```
PS> 'ABCD' -replace "([AC])(.)",'$2-$1'
B-AD-C
```

results in `B-AD-C`.

What's the period significance here? cant find the meaning which tells me how to use it, I have tried removing it and it results in

```
PS> 'ABCD' -replace "([AC])",'$2-$1' 
$2-AB$2-CD
```

Why the period is significant with capture groups in regex?

I am in this for almost a week now but not able to find the exact meaning.

Any help would be appreciated on this.

Regards
Merry X'Mas

Comment: Sorry, at the starting forum trimmed the signature,

Comment: the signature is like:

[string](0..9|%{[char][int](32+(".......................").substring(($_*2),2))})-replace "\s{1}\b"

Answer (score 1):

I think you are supposed to replace the dots with digits.

For each digit *n* from 0 to 9, pick the *n*'th pair of digits in the string, add 32, and convert to that Unicode character. Then remove every space that comes before a word character.

32 is the code for a space (" "), and is followed by 94 printable characters. See [List of Unicode characters, Basic Latin (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin) for a list.

`[string]`, `[char]`, and `[int]` converts a value to the specified type. The `% { }` syntax is short for `ForEach-Object { }`.

The regex at the end, matches one space character, followed by a word-boundary. —That is, it matches zero characters but only before a word-character (A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and "_")).

The full syntax is: *string* `-replace` *regex* `,` *replacement*. Since there are no replacement specified, it defaults to the empty string. Effectively removes any space before a letter or digit.

---

For the regex `([AC])(.)`, it will match any `A` or `C` followed by another character. It will capture the `A` or `C` into group one, and the following character into group 2.

Simple `( )` creates a capture group, and allows you to refer to the matched substring elsewhere. `.` is a wildcard, and matches any character except newline (U+00A0).

```
ABCD -> {
  Match 1 = {
    Text = "AB"
    Capture 1 = { Text = "A" }
    Capture 2 = { Text = "B" }
  }
  Match 2 = {
    Text = "CD"
    Capture 1 = { Text = "C" }
    Capture 2 = { Text = "D" }
  }
}
```

The replacement string `$2-$1` says to put the text captured into group 2 first, followed by a dash, followed by the text captured into group 1.

`$1` refers to the text captured into group 1, and `$2` refers to the text captured into group 2. Match 1 will be replaced by "B-A", and Match 2 by "D-C", resulting in "B-AD-C".

A good source for the syntax and mechanics of regex is http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thanks Markus for your help and now I somewhat understand the signature well.

Comment: I would also appreciate if you could throw some light on the second part of the question. Thanks for your guidance. :)